# getting No such file or directory error for cron job

Tags: cron

I wanted to run the following file from a `cron` job and got `No such file or directory` error, please help.

```
/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/filename.php
```

Comment: Could you post your cron statement here?

Comment: i used realpath($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']) to get path of file

Answer (score 0):

Just use a service like WebBasedCron (google it) to schedule your cron job remotely.  If you can access the filename.php file from a browser like FireFox, then you can execute the cron job.